# adding a lighting glLightfv method is not working

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, lighting, ambient

i am tring to add a light. but when i try to modify the position netbeans highlights the gl.glLightfv method. its not just with the position its with diffuse and ambient too... what i am do wrong... here is my code.

all the hits say that:

no suitable method found for glLightfv(int,int,float[])
method javax.media.opengl.GL.glLightfv(int,int,float[],int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method javax.media.opengl.GL.glLightfv(int,int,java.nio.FloatBuffer) is not applicable
(actual argument float[] cannot be converted to java.nio.FloatBuffer by method invocation conversion)

```
float pos[] = {-2.0f, 2.0f, -3.0f, 1.0f };
gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_POSITION, pos); //underlinded red:
float dif[] = {1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f};
gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_DIFFUSE, dif);  //underlinded red:
float amb[] = {0.2f,0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f};
gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_AMBIENT, amb);  //underlinded red:
```

Comment: It looks like the compiler doesn't like the float array, and instead expects a FloatBuffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `float array` instead of `FloatBuffer` class, you'll have to add one more parameter, which says where (in the array) should OpenGL start look for your parameters -> array index offset value..

In your case

```
float pos[] = {-2.0f, 2.0f, -3.0f, 1.0f };
gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_POSITION, pos, 0);
float dif[] = {1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f};
gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_DIFFUSE, dif, 0);
float amb[] = {0.2f,0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f};
gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_AMBIENT, amb, 0);
```